# adding active class bootstrap carousel at repeat data just on first key in react app

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-carousel

I'm looking how to make a repeat item carousel which has if just key 0 that have class action if I using it in return it's error and if I using variable in return pug `.carousel-item${activeornot}`

```
return _.map(this.props.editor_pick_data, function (value, key){
  if(key == 0){

  }
  return (
    pug`
    .carousel-item.active(key=${key}, style=${{display: 'relative'}})
      .col-md-3.col-sm-6.col-xs-12npm
        a.thumbnail(href="#")
          img.img-responsive(src=${value.item.images[1].big_thumbnail})
  `
  )
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're just trying to add `active` class if `key === 0`. I think you can have a `className` variable as well:

```
className=${key == 0 ? 'active' : ''}
```

-

```
renderCarouselItem() {
  return _.map(this.props.editor_pick_data, function(value, key) {
    return (
      pug`
      .carousel-item(key=${key}, style=${{display: 'relative'}}, className=${key == 0 ? 'active' : ''})
        .col-md-3.col-sm-6.col-xs-12npm
          a.thumbnail(href="#")
            img.img-responsive(src=${value.item.images[1].big_thumbnail})
      `
    );
  })
}
```

Comment: oh that the structure how implementation it. thanks work perfectly

Comment: automatic sliding has stopped working after i changed code to `className=${key == 0 ? 'active' : ''}` this. Any clue?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can do something like this:

```
className={`carousel-item ${key == 0 ? 'active' : ''}`}
```

Comment: Also, explain a bit how it would solve the problem, what changes you made, and its impact.

Answer (score 0):

this work but i dont know this is the best practice

```
 renderCarouselItem() {
    return _.map(this.props.editor_pick_data, function (value, key){
      let html = [];
      if(key == 0){
        html.push(pug`
        .carousel-item.active(key=${key}, style=${{display: 'relative'}})
          .col-md-3.col-sm-6.col-xs-12npm
            a.thumbnail(href="#")
              img.img-responsive(src=${value.item.images[1].big_thumbnail})
        `)
      }else{
        html.push(pug`
        .carousel-item(key=${key}, style=${{display: 'relative'}})
          .col-md-3.col-sm-6.col-xs-12npm
            a.thumbnail(href="#")
              img.img-responsive(src=${value.item.images[1].big_thumbnail})
        `)
      }

      return (
        pug`
          ${html[0]}
        `
      )
    })
  }
```